# Bubble sort Array program, Selecting a certain number

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to find a number out of a random set of X amount of numbers. I don't want you to put it in yourself I would just like suggestions so I can learn.

What my code does it allows me to display any amount of random numbers I would like. I can't search within those numbers and that's where I'm lost. 
**CODE DISPLAYS NO ERRORS.** *"Stepping into" is still new to me.*

```
Private Sub GenerateAndSearch(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSort.Click, btnGenerate.Click
        Static intDataArray(-1) As Integer
        Dim btnButtonClicked As Button = sender

        Select Case btnButtonClicked.Tag
            Case "Generate Array"
                Call GenerateSortedArray(intDataArray)

                Me.lstbox1.Items.Clear()
                Call DisplayData(intDataArray, Me.lstbox1, "Sorted array:")

            Case "Search Array"
                Dim intNumToFind As Integer = Val(Me.txtNumElements.Text)
                Dim intNumFoundIndex As Integer

                intNumFoundIndex = BinarySearch(intDataArray, intNumToFind)
                If intNumFoundIndex = -1 Then
                    Me.Label1.Text = "Number not found."
                Else
                    Me.Label1.Text = "Number found at index" & intNumFoundIndex
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is there the possibility that a random number may be generated twice?  If so, which one do you want returned?  And is the array sorted? (I see you called it SortedArray, but just want to make sure.)

Comment: You might want to do `Dim btnButtonClicked As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)`. And use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).

Comment: set a breakpoint on the call to `BinarySearch` a) does the array look like you think it should (size, contents, sorted order etc) b) if no, back up and debug the array maker c) if yes, step into the search proc and debug it